# PHP: What is happening in the round() function?

Tags: php, rounding

I get a time in seconds from my database (stored as an integer):

```
$time = $data["USER_TIME"];
```

And then i do the following:

```
$hours = round(($time / 3600), 0);
$minutes = round((($time - ($hours * 3600)) / 60), 0);
$seconds = $time - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);
```

And i create a time string after:

```
$timeString = formatNumber($hours).":".formatNumber($minutes).":".formatNumber($seconds);

function formatNumber($number) {
    if($number < 10) {
        return ("0".$number);
    } else {
        return ("".$number);    
    }
}
```

But the results are confusing for me:

```
10 seconds -> 00:00:10
15 seconds -> 00:00:15
20 seconds -> 00:00:20
25 seconds -> 00:00:25
30 seconds -> 00:01:-30
35 seconds -> 00:01:-25
40 seconds -> 00:01:-20
45 seconds -> 00:01:-15
50 seconds -> 00:01:-10
```

Can someone explain me what is happening here?

Var_dump $data["USER_TIME"] :

```
10 
15
20 
25
30
35
40
45
50
```

Comment: Var_dump $data["USER_TIME"] and let us see whats in there

Comment: Haha, the correct times wasnt the expected answer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try it with `floor`. You are using `round` now, which means everything equal to or above .5 becomes the next integer.

```
$hours = floor($time / 3600);
$minutes = floor(($time - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
$seconds = $time - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes * 60);
```

Comment: correct answer. thank you. can you explain the difference between floor and round?

Comment: `Round` rounds the value. `round(1.4)` returns 1, `round(1.5)` returns 2. With decimals it's more precise: `round(1.554,2)` returns 1.55. etc. etc.
`floor` always returns the next lowest integer `floor(1.9)` returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gmdate()` function instead of using `floor()` and `round()`.

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 685);
```